# Specifying a Single Request To Use Credentials with HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient

I am using OAuth2 on my android project. The idea is to use a singleton HttpClient used with a ThreadSafeClientConnManager.

For a normal request to the server we construct an Authorization header and send that. The header is constructed from values received from the server. This works fine. However every 15 minutes we must get new values from the server to construct the header. To Received these values I must set the credentials like so.

```
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(creds.clientId, creds.clientSecret));
```

In order for this to work I must set up and new DefaultHttpClient. If I use the original singleton httpclient I receive some errors. My question is.. is it possible to set the credentials to be used only on this one request?

I noticed that there is an AuthScope. The host and port would not be suitable for this but maybe the realm would? I can't find anything that tells me what a realm is or how to use it.

> 06-05 10:12:55.969: W/System.err(23843):
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to
>   respond 06-05 10:12:55.969: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
>   06-05 10:12:55.969: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
>   06-05 10:12:55.969: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
>   06-05 10:12:55.969: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
>   06-05 10:12:55.969: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
>   06-05 10:12:55.975: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
>   06-05 10:12:55.975: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
>   06-05 10:12:55.975: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:504)
>   06-05 10:12:55.975: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   06-05 10:12:55.975: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   06-05 10:12:55.975: W/System.err(23843):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)

So After more testing I have found where the problem lies.

I want to configure a pooled connection manager like so

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
schemeRegistry.register(
        new Scheme("https", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));


ClientConnectionManager conManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(new BasicHttpParams(), schemeRegistry);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(conManager, new BasicHttpParams());
```

But when configure like this, I get the error above. If I use the normal default httpclient like so

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Then it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one requests needs basic auth credentials, and apparently calling `setCredentials()` causes an error, your best be might be to not use the credentials provider at all and set the Basic auth header manually (using `setHeader()` on the request) only when you need it.

Edit: Here's how you should create a threadsafe shared HttpClient instance:

```
 DefaultHttpClient createHttpclient(int timeout) {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params,
                HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeout);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "MyApp/1.0");
        ConnPerRoute connPerRoute = new ConnPerRouteBean(10);
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, connPerRoute);
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 20);

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
        ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
                schemeRegistry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
    }
```

Comment: I updated so show the errors when I try this method.

Yes I am using that to request the access token or refresh token. We are following this draft http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25.pdf

Comment: Apparently the server is not responding. Are you sure you are sending the correct header?. How exactly does the header you send look like? What is the server expecting?

Comment: There are no headers required when requesting the access/refresh token. The server is expecting the credentials to be set and an entity to be within a post request. If I use 1 HttpClient for the actual requests to the resource server and another to send the requests to get the access token it works fine. However I want to use 1 httpclient as a singleton.

Comment: OK, so one requests needs basic auth credentials, and the other doesn't. So you either `client.getCredentialsProvider().clear()` when you don't need them, and then call `client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials()` again when you do need them or just use two separate instances. Or, forget the credentials provider and set the Basic auth header manually (using `setHeader()` on the request) only when you need it.

Comment: Ah yeah of course. I didn't think to construct a basic Auth header myself! Maybe if you update the answer with that I can award the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I should have been a little clearer. The setCredentials causes the error. I used Basic header instead

Comment: Updated again, but still not sure why calling `setCredentials()` causes an error. Might be a bug -- the HttpClient in Android is rather old.

Comment: Sorry, I have just realised there is more to it. Even the header wasn't as expected. I have updated my question

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an HTTPS URL (_https://somehost.com)? If so, you obviously cannot use the PlainSocketFactory for port 443.

Comment: It wasn't so obvious for me but it certainly seems to be the problem. I was using https with the calls to OAuth and http with the calls to the actual API. It makes sense. Thanks a lot for your patients.